Python script sometimes gets stuck trying to execute specific SQL file
I have a python script which executes many SQL files, one after another, using psycopg.
One of these SQLs, let's call it X.sql, seems to be problematic in that sometimes the script is not able to advance past it. I have console output which shows when the script attempts to execute each SQL file. It shows X.sql last and appears to be doing nothing while still running.
X.sql is a bit more complicated than the other SQLs, so maybe it takes some time to execute.
However, when I run:
Select * from pg_stat_activity where state not ilike 'idle%'
I do not see the contents of X.sql in the query column, so it seems to simply not be running on the database and my script is completely idle, waiting for the query to finish execution.
Also, if I execute X.sql in SQL Workbench on the same DB with the same user, it works fine.
Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going on?
Here is the function which works for all other SQL files (also using the same conn - autocommit is on):
def execute_SQL_query(conn, file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        query = file.read()

    print("Executing SQL: {}".format(file_path))
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        try:
            cursor.execute(query)
        except Exception as e:
            e.add_note("SQL file which caused the error: %s" % file_path)
            e.add_note("DB connection info: %s" % conn.info.get_parameters())
            raise

I am using Psycopg 3.1.18, Python 3.12, and PostgreSQL
Edit: I need this to be automated, i.e., to work without human intervention. I just ran it after a failed attempt (with generated tables from failed attempt still existing - script skips SQL when it seems to have already executed) and it worked. Could it be that I need to renew the connection object every so often? I need to know this for sure for the automation.


You need to show the query 2) I don't see that you commit anywhere. 3) Look at the Postgres log to see what is happening. You may need to crank up the logging depending on what type of query it is.




What could be in the query that could cause this? It's selects, joins, aggregations etc. Psycopg reports errors from Postgres anyway. (Query is quite large and contains business-sensitive material)


Sorry, forgot to mention autocommit is on.


Thanks for the tip! Have never done this before, will give it a shot.



Update: I'm reformulating/optimizing the query. Maybe I will post it when I'm done, if the problem persists.
